# Python can't import from the same directory?

Tags: python, python-import

I have the following directory structure (I didn't write this so I'm assuming it has to work somehow?):

```
tool.py
core/
  __init__.py
  config.py
  common.py
```

`tool.py` indirectly imports `config.py`, and `config.py` has a line `from common import foo`, which displays the following error:

```
...
  File "...\core\config.py", line 5, in <module>
    from common import foo
ImportError: No module named 'common'
```

It probably isn't relevant, but I'm using Python 3.4 on Windows, and the `tool.py` directory is in the system path (I'm simply running it as `tool`).

Answer (score 5):

Use a relative import:

```
from .common import foo
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use relative imports

```
from .common import foo
```

Python 3 makes a distinction between absolute and relative imports and doesn't support implicit relative imports which you could use in Python 2.x.